# Zabbix "fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution"

Tags: php, ansible, cloud, zabbix

I appear to be having a dns issue, but I'm not clear about which machine is having the issue, or what domain is failing to be resolved.

I followed these instructions, but I changed the IP addresses so they would point to my linode servers instead of the vagrant VMs. https://blog.zabbix.com/installing-the-zabbix-server-with-ansible/13317/

Now I have a dashboard, but it says the zabbix server is not running and there is a PHP error. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

```
fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution [zabbix.php:22 → require_once() → ZBase->run() → ZBase->processRequest() → ZBase->processResponseFinal() → CView->getOutput() → include() → make_status_of_zbx() → get_status() → CZabbixServer->isRunning() → CZabbixServer->request() → CZabbixServer->connect() → fsockopen() in include/classes/server/CZabbixServer.php:539]
    fsockopen(): Unable to connect to node-1:10051 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution) [zabbix.php:22 → require_once() → ZBase->run() → ZBase->processRequest() → ZBase->processResponseFinal() → CView->getOutput() → include() → make_status_of_zbx() → get_status() → CZabbixServer->isRunning() → CZabbixServer->request() → CZabbixServer->connect() → fsockopen() in include/classes/server/CZabbixServer.php:539]
```

Answer (score 0):

You left `node-1` as Server Address in zabbix_web configuration, instead of pointing to your server. You can now change `$ZBX_SERVER` variable in  `/etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php`.